# RedHat init.d script will not start with service after stop

Tags: rhel, init.d, chkconfig

I have the service script below, which calls a shell script. We changed something in the script When I run the shell script directly, everything works fine. When I restart the servER, everything works fine. If I call `sudo service my-service stop` then `sudo service my-service start`, it will stop, but never start again. It says systemctl OK, but a process never kicks off, and no logs are ever written from the shell script. Even if I call `sudo /etc/init.d/my-service` it won't start. Again, mind you, this will start fine automatically on restart of the server. Any thoughts on what could be the problem, or how to get better logging from this failed start?

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# my-service
#
# chkconfig: 345 84 15
# description:  Start up the My Service process.
# config: /etc/sysconfig/my-service
# processname: java

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

# Loading the configuration parameters.
if [ -f /etc/sysconfig/my-service ]; then
  source /etc/sysconfig/my-service
fi

RETVAL=0

case "$1" in
 start)
        if [ -f /opt/my-service/latest/bin/my-service-start.sh ];
          then
            logger -s "Starting My Service"
            /bin/su -p -s /bin/sh myserviceuser /opt/my-service/latest/bin/my-service-start.sh
            RETVAL=$?
            [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/my-service
        fi
        ;;
 stop)
        if [ -f /opt/my-service/latest/bin/my-service-stop.sh ];
          then
            logger -s "Stopping My Service"
            /bin/su -p -s /bin/sh myserviceuser /opt/my-service/latest/bin/my-service-stop.sh
            RETVAL=$?
            [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/my-service
        fi
        ;;
 restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
 *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Comment: Did you ensure that `/var/lock/subsys/my-service` is removed after you stop the service?

Answer (score 0):

"We changed something in the script"

There is not enough information to authoritatively answer this question, since the contents of `my-service-start.sh` and `my-service-stop.sh` are a mystery.

Assuming everything you have said is true, then the case is that `my-service-start.sh` does not function as intended, once `my-service-start.sh` and `my-service-stop.sh` have both already been run. Even though it works fine at the first startup. This means something is altered after the scripts have been run. Things are not the same as they were when the start script ran successfully. Maybe a port your start script needs is still tied up.

I suggest looking into PID file handling to stop your script from potentially stepping on itself, and analyse your *start/stop* scripts for what is being altered. Try adding some error handling to your start script and see if that helps you isolate the problem.

Comment: What I meant here is that if I alter anything in the start script, the init.d service fails to start. The shell scripts continue to work when run directly, without any issues, and without any port stepping. Logging exists in the shell scripts, the service just seems to NEVER call the shell script, and there is ZERO logging from the service to indicate that the shell script has been run, or what the error is.

Comment: In fact, if I run the command `/bin/su -p -s /bin/sh myserviceuser /opt/my-service/latest/bin/my-service-start.sh` "my-service" indeed runs, and logs and works as expected. The question is whether I missed a step in how the above script is written, the services it uses to act as a service, and whether something needs to be called when a slight modification is made to the target scripts.

Comment: A pointer on what logging to add to the service script, and where to look for said logging would be appreciated. There seems to be no output other than "OK" from systemctl, which is obviously not the case.

Comment: Is it logging 'Starting my service' or 'Stopping my service'? logger should be writing to /var/log/messages or /var/log/syslog. Since your script works fine when you run the command, maybe you don't need all that at the top with the source function library and configuration parameters. I would aim at making the init as simple as possible and make your start/stop scripts do the rest.

Comment: The init script works fine initially, but the logger tip is a good one. I'll try to modify and see what the result might be. Thanks.

Comment: Did you use RHEL 6.x or RHEL 7.x ? chkconfig or service on RHEL 6.x and systemd with systemctl on RHEL 7.x. Shell script ran as root on systemd. Some command line will not work well. I had tried "notify-send" command. Notification did not pop up when ran it on systemd.